# How do i troubleshoot the vurnabilities problem caused while i am trying to install express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, version-control

I am facing this problem while installing my node express.js "https://npmjs.com/advisories/785"
 Package         clean-css

Patched in      >=4.1.11

Dependency of   jade

Path            jade > clean-css

More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/785

found 4 vulnerabilities (3 low, 1 critical) in 217 scanned packages
  4 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.

C:\Users\User\express_example>cd express_example && npm install
The system cannot find the path specified.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not setting the node path correctly in the environment variable.

Please provide the correct path and check if node is accessible via command line /terminal by writing:

```
node -v
```

followed by:

```
npm -v
```

Comment: This does not show any error and is displaying the version successfully.

Comment: Meaning, Node and NPM are installed successfully and if the problem is coming from npm install then its coming from one of the NPM package. For whichever package the error is coming , Try checking its npm and github repo for dependencies.